# Parallax effect causing container to overlap on my menu bar

Tags: html, css

I currently have a parallax effect which is shows all the padding correctly on screen sizes greater than 1700px in width.

But if make the browser smaller or use a computer that has a resolution of 1600px, the text will overflow onto my sidebar and this only happens on my index page because of the parralex.

HTML

```
 <header style="height: 1000px; width 100px">
       <section>
        ..navigation bar
       </section>

      <div id="page-content-wrapper">
          <div id ="text_slider">
              <div><p>Text 1</p></div>
                  <div><p> Text 2</p></div>
                     <div><p> Text 3</p></div>
                  </div>
           </div>
      </div>
     <script>

        $('#text_slider div:first')
            .fadeOut(500).next().fadeIn(1000).end().appendTo('#text_slider');

        }, 3000);
    </script>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
header{
    background: url(../img/orange.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: top center !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

[This is the image with a smaller sized browser at 1700px](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7IQV2.png)

[This is the image with a smaller sized browser at 1800px +](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9SDZ.png)

Comment: Can you make a live version for us to pick at (http://jsfiddle.net, etc)?

Comment: #page-content-wrapper is set to position: absolute, changing it to relative fixes it.

Comment: That has already been set to relative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U have combined css with html. please refer bootstrap 3.

u used the container-fluid  within the container.

change ur class="col-sm-10.col-md-9.pull-right" 
into 
class="col-sm-10 col-md-9 pull-right" in html

Comment: Thank you so much! Didn't notice  what I did and the change in class names.